# "WSDL2Java" vs "JAX-WS Proxy" vs "JAX-WS Dispatch APIs"

Tags: soap, cxf, jax-ws

Apache CXF mentions five different options for consuming a web-service: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html#HowdoIdevelopaclient?-BuildingClients

WSDL2Java generated Client,
JAX-WS Proxy,
JAX-WS Dispatch APIs,
Simple Frontend Client Proxy,
Dynamic Client

While there is some explanation of when to use 'Simple Frontend Client Proxy' and 'Dynamic Client', but for the other three it is not very clear about scenarios when one would be preferred over the others. Looking for answers or any helpful links about it.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS APIs are probably not explained in detail, because they are part of the specification: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224

For a typical usecase I would recommend to follow the WSDL2Java approach which is also described here: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html

The Dispatch API allows you to develop clients more dynamically. If that's interesting for you, you should read chapter 4.3 of the spec.